# The best practice to develop a JavaScript linting tool for my own language?

Tags: javascript, lint, codemirror

I have designed a domain-specific language. I want to build a web-based editor for the users of my language.

So far, I have successfully provided syntax highlighting via CodeMirror. The demo is here: http://casbin.org/editor/. Now I want to add the syntax validation. Based on [CodeMirror's docs](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addons), it uses `lint/lint.js` to support syntax validation and provides `html-lint.js`, `json-lint.js`, `javascript-lint.js`, `coffeescript-lint.js`, and `css-lint.js` as examples. But as shown below, these examples are just wrappers and they all invoke external lint tools written in js, such as `htmlhint.js`, `jsonlint.js`, etc.

1. `html-lint.js` -> [HTMLHint](https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint)
2. `json-lint.js` -> [JSON Lint](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint)
3. `javascript-lint.js` -> [JSHint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint)
4. `coffeescript-lint.js` -> [CoffeeLint](https://github.com/clutchski/coffeelint)
5. `css-lint.js` -> [CSSLint](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint)

So it seems that I need to develop such a lint tool for my own language first before making a wrapper for CodeMirror.

The question is: is there any common interface or helper library or widely-recognized guideline/documentation when developing a lint tool for a custom language in js?